# How to highlight a part of string from given string in Javascript/Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex, string

I have a string

```
   var inputStr = 'xzy';

   var match = 'x';
```

I have to highlight the `str` from the `inputStr`. I was trying something like this

```
var inputStr = "vikram";
var match = 'v';
var new_str = str.split('');

for(var i = 0;i<=new_str.length;i++)
{
    if(match == new_str[i])
    {
         var x_str += ''//code to bold that charachter and add in the array 
    }

}
```

Can any one please help me fix this

Thanks in advance

Comment: what is length.new_str??

Comment: You're looking for `string.replace`.

Comment: @Neel sorry it was a typo . I fixed it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd suggest, at first glance:

```
var inputStr = inputStr.replace(new RegExp('(' + str + ')', 'g'), '<strong>$1</strong>');
```

Comment: What is `str` has a special character like `(` or `$` or `.`

Comment: @anubhava in my case it will not have any special character because I was trying to modify the . Old Auto complete plugin of Jquery . It is already filtering the special characters . this is more than enough :).

Answer (score 1):

For your question i found that you want to implement a search similar to that of the browser
check out the Fiddle that i have created hope that helpes you.

```
[http://jsfiddle.net/raLnLyb4/][1]

var $search = 'vi';
var $names = $('.search_string p');
  var match = RegExp($search, 'gi');
  $names.filter(function(){ return match.test($(this).text()) })
    .html(function(){
      if (!$search) return $(this).text();
      return $(this).text().replace(match, '<span class="highlight">$&</span>');
});
```